# Mongoose - How to create a common method for all models?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a common method I need to implement for all models. Right now I do it for each model:

```
var Product = module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

module.exports.flush = function (filename, cb) {
  "use strict";

  var collection = require(filename);

  // todo: reimplement with promises
  this.remove({}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      this.create(collection, cb);
    }
  }.bind(this));
};
```

How can I add this method once so it existed for all models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define your function for `Model`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Model.flush = function (filename, cb) {
  "use strict";

  var collection = require(filename);

  // todo: reimplement with promises
  this.remove({}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      this.create(collection, cb);
    }
  }.bind(this));
};
```

Then all your created models will inherit the `flush` function:

```
var Product = module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
Product.flush();
```

Comment: So great so simple! Thank you!